# Jupyter notebook new cell in reversed order?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The default setting of Jupyter notebook is after each execution, new cell is generated and the cursor goes to the new cell.

Is there a way to add new cell above the current one after execution, and go to the newly generated cell? (Instead of top to bottom, goes from bottom to top, so to speak.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can there is option add cell above or below

[image: Snap]

.goto Help->edit keyboard shortcut (select and modify available options)

Comment: Probably I should make my question clear, but I meant _automatically_ create the new cell at the top **AFTER** the execution (but not _manually_ insert cell above).

Comment: @udothemath1984 Got it ..goto Help->edit keyboard shortcut

Comment: Add any combination of key shortcut

Comment: Thanks @HariomSingh, I am able to activate the action in command mode by two steps using "run cell" (press u) + "insert cell above" (press 7). Is it possible to go one step further, say press 8 (**one** desired key) at command mode and make these two steps in one action?

Comment: @udothemath1984 Nothing wrong in trying .if it helped please do accept the answer